# What is the probability that a sum of n random numbers modulo k is zero?

Tags: probability, summation, modular-arithmetic

Given $n$ uniformly random natural numbers less than $k$, what is the probability that (where $N_m$ is the $m$th of the $n$ selected numbers):
$$\sum_{m=1}^n N_m \,\, \text{mod} \,\, k = 0$$
For the case of $n = 1$, it seems like the answer is $\frac{1}{k}$. But I'm confused what happens when $n > 1$. Playing with different numbers it seems maybe the probability is always $\frac{1}{k}$. I think this, because for any sequence of numbers only the last one seems to matter, and only one number can make the sum = 0.

But that confuses me. I thought that, in general, the sum of uniformly random numbers will form a normal distribution. Is this wrong when you are working modulo some number? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: What do you mean by $n_m$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee I mean the mth item in the sequence of n numbers. Apologies for the bad notation. I'll edit in a fix.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of two (or more) independent uniformly distributed numbers $\bmod k$ is itself uniformly distributed $\bmod k$.

One way (and there are many others) to see this is by considering the  $k\times k$ matrix $A$ whose $(i,j)$ entry is $i+j\bmod k$. Each number in this matrix occurs an equal number of times (namely $k$ times), the pattern of occurrence of these occurrences should be obvious on inspection. (This is teacher's coded, passive-aggressive language for *right now, construct and write down $A$ for some small value of $k$, such as $k=3$*.)  The connection with probability is simple: you select a row $i$ and a column $j$ at random, uniformly; the chance that you get an $s$ as the sum is exactly  $k$ out of $k\times k$, because the number $s$ appears exactly $k$ times in the array $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability modulo k is the same as the probability of a fixed interval in a uniform distribution. It is always the same because it's uniform. If you have modulo k, then you will have K numbers. and each with probability $\frac{1}{k}$